# only assignment call increment decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#

I am making a game in Unity and i have no idea why i am getting this error. I would appreciate if you guys can help me.

```
private enum States
{
    NewGame,
    Cell,
    Sheets, 
    Mirror, 
    Lock, 
    Key, 
    Escape
}

private States my_state;

void state_cell()
{
    text.text = "You are in a jail captured by Indians, you have to escape at all cost. You have to " +
                "aware the Pakistan Army about the evil plans of indians, and you got minimal time left " +
                "\n\n Press S to view the Sheets, press R to return, Press M to get the Mirror,press " +
                "L to view the Lock, and press M to make Key";
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        (my_state = States.Sheets);
    }
}
void state_sheets()
{
    text.text = "Press S to view the sheets which has info about the security lock, There is some wet " +
                "mud and a metal things lying around see if you can make a key for the Lock " +
                "Also you wanna cut some piece from the Mirror hanging on the wall to find the " +
                "measurements of the Lock";

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        (my_state = States.Cell);
    }
}
```

Also i am using monodevelop version 4.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Your parenthesis here are useless and cause the compiler error:

```
(my_state = States.Sheets);
```

This will do:

```
my_state = States.Sheets;
```

Parenthesis are only allowed in a number of cases, for example with `if ()` or `((CastTo)a)` statements. This is not one of those cases: don't put parenthesis around assignments.

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses around `(my_state = States.Sheets)` etc are the problem, as they are performing the assigning and then returning a value, which in this case will be the value assigned.  The compiler doesn't understand what to do here - it's like having a line of code that says `123;`.